# mvc fileresult 2 questions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got 2 problems here:

The function:

```
public ActionResult File(Guid Id, string Name)
    {
        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            var file = db.Attachments.Where(s => s.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (file == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return File(file.Path, file.ContentType, file.OriginalName + file.Extension);
        }           
    }
```

It works fine except I want the browser to decide download this file or show in it. Now it automatically downoads the .png Image, since normally, if I click such link, it would show this image to me. How can I do this?

And the second problem:
Here is my route to this function:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Files", url: "file/{id}/{file}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "File",
                       id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                       file = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When I set `file` parameter to. for example, `1.png` it will throw 404 ecxeption. As I understand this happens while it looks for file directly on the server, but not throught my function. How can I make this route to always call this function?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I haven't fully wrapped my mind around your first problem, but about 2nd, I don't think MVC can handle routes with file extensions.

Comment: @DaveA My first problem is it just starting file download and not showing the file in a browser like normally when it is an image....